# Echo php image gallery

Tags: php

I used http://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/index.html to parse gallery, but not working. I need help!

**My code:**

```
<div data-nanogallery2='{
    "itemsBaseURL": "http://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/samples/",
    "thumbnailWidth": "auto",
    "thumbnailHeight": "auto",
    "thumbnailDisplayInterval": 30,
    "thumbnailLabel": {
        "display": false
    },
    "displayBreadcrumb": false,
    "breadcrumbAutoHideTopLevel": false,
    "breadcrumbOnlyCurrentLevel": false,
    "thumbnailOpenImage": false
}'>

<?php foreach($arr_img as $img) { ?>
    <a href="#" data-ngthumb="<?php echo $img; ?>"></a>
<?php } ?>

</div>
```

It show, but all echo `$img` are in 1 line like this:

[image]

Help me, how to fix, thanks!

Comment: Whats wrong with it, seems absolute correct to me. Did you load jqeury, the framework script and css files correctly ? Are there any errors in your console ? What does it show (image of result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework you chosed works for self hosted images. You try to work with external flickr links, the syntax here ii a liitle bit different e.g.

```
<div data-nanogallery2='{
        "userID": "149035168@N08", //User-Id
        "kind": "flickr", //Content type, google images is also supported
        "photoset": "72157675715292251", //The set of photos you want
        "thumbnailWidth": "200",
        "thumbnailDisplayInterval": 30
      }'>
```

The best will be if you read the official documentation to implement your pictures: http://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/datasource.html#ngy2_flickr

If you want just specific images you can do this by working with the `whiteList` attribute.